# Laravel how to stop/restart workers of a specific queue?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue

I know you can stop all workers in Laravel using `queue:restart`. But I'm looking for a way to stop all workers working on a specific queue. Something like this:

```
php artisan queue:restart --queue=my_queue
```

Comment: To clarify you want to stop a specific worker or all workers working on a specific queue (which could be one or more)?

Comment: Good point @apokryfos, let's say I want to stop all workers of a specific queue

Comment: If you are using supervisor you can [restart or stop all queue workers that are associated with a specific group](https://serverfault.com/questions/586708/how-can-i-control-a-whole-supervisor-group-at-once), however this is not going to be a graceful restart since the workers will be killed even if they are in the middle of processing a job

Comment: Supervisor is not an option for me since I'm on windows

Comment: How are you running the queue workers then?

Comment: Via php's `proc_open()` I start a new cmd window running `queue:work --queue=sth`. `proc_open` is triggered via a user request or a main worker which I start manually.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I read the documentation,

```
php artisan queue:clear redis --queue=emails
```

is only available for The SQS, Redis, and database queue drivers.

But this command is clearing, not stopping.

Answer (score 0):

using queue:restart     - this will stop jobs processing and leave them in the table

use queue:work    to start jos being processed

This is useful if you are expecting a number of emails to be generated and want to check they are actually being generated.